# Entity Framework entity how to set ID and foreign key constraint?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some Entity Framework 6 entities generated from a database-first database. 
They look similar to the code below.

Notice there is a `CustomerID`, and a `Customer` field, where the `Customer` field is from the`FK_Contact_Customer`.

When dealing with an instance of this entity in C#, should I be setting the `CustomerID`, or the `Customer`?  And once I set one property, how do I make the other consistent?  Is this a manual process?  Is there an Entity Framework helper for this?

For example, if I have an instance of a Contact entity and an instance of a `Customer` entity, what is the correct way of associating the `Contact.Customer` to the `Customer` instance?  I would expect after this is done, that both the `CustomerID` and `Customer` properties would be consistent with the association.

NOTE: This is probably a duplicate question, I did search, but could not find the answer to this (basic) question.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyProject.DAL.Context
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Contact
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string Contact1 { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// FK_Contact_Customer
        /// </summary>
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate the Customer Property so it looks like this.

```
[ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

The CustomerID property will not have to be set manually if you use the foreign keyed property.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Justin!  Quick follow-up question, since I did "database first", if I ever regenerate the class, then I would have to re-add the annotations correct?  Is there any way to have EF generate these annotations during the autogeneration?

Comment: @Turtle1363 I have written several of these database first model classes by hand instead of autogeneration. There is probably a better way to do it but that is the method I am aware of. Someone else may know better.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the FluetAPI with migrations to map your Entitys to the database

Lest's create a class named ContactConfig, that class will create all the relationship of that entity.

```
public class ContactConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
 {
    public ContactConfig()
    {

        HasKey(c => c.ID);

        Property(c => c.Contact1 )
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.Email )
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.ContactTitle )
            .IsRequired();

        //Here is the secret
        HasRequired(c => c.Costumer)
            .WithMany(c => c.Contact)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerID);
  }
}
```

The CostumerID is just a navigation property, and will be the foreign key of the Costumer class. You have to associate the ID of the Costumer class with the CostumerID property in the Contact class.

With this setting, you simply call the CostumerID property when you need to associate a costumer with a contact

After that, just type Update-Database in the package Manager Console.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are trying to create a new Contact which will be related to an existing Customer in which case you would populate Contact.CustomerID and leave Contact.Customer null.
Contact.CustomerID is the foreign key to the Customer entity.
Contact.Customer is a navigation property from Contact to Customer that you would use when reading data out, so accessing Contact.Customer would give you the related Customer entity.

I'm not sure of the implications of creating the Contact with Customer populated, it may cause the Customer entity to be updated, or if Customer ID is not populated it may create a new Customer record to be created and related to the Contact. This is not an approach I would take and it may require configuration.